# A support for analyzing the excerpt from the latest edition of the Economist

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Just need your insights on the analysis of the following sentence taken from the latest edition of the Economist from the Business section.

The original excerpt :

> The American firm, which is building a gigafactory not far from VW’s headquarters, presumably views Germany’s system of powerful worker representation on boards as a cautionary tale.

My question is what is the difference between the original excerpt and the following ones :

Option 1:

> The American firm which is building a gigafactory not far from VW’s headquarters presumably views Germany’s system of powerful worker representation on boards as a cautionary tale.

Option 2:

> The American firm building a gigafactory not far from VW’s headquarters presumably views Germany’s system of powerful worker representation on boards as a cautionary tale.

Option 3:

> The American firm that builds a gigafactory not far from VW’s headquarters presumably views Germany’s system of powerful worker representation on boards as a cautionary tale.

I am pretty much sitting on the fence when it comes to using the aforementioned options and I would appreciate it if you could shine a light on the nuances in using those options.

Answer (score 0):

> Option 1: The American firm which is building a gigafactory not far from VW’s headquarters presumably views Germany’s system of powerful worker representation on boards as a cautionary tale.

By removing the commas, you have changed the phrase "which is building a gigafactory not far from VW's headquarters" from an aside providing additional information to a restrictive clause that identifies which firm is being discussed. With the original wording, presumably the firm was already named in a previous sentence so this restrictive clause is not necessary.

> Option 2: The American firm building a gigafactory not far from VW’s headquarters presumably views Germany’s system of powerful worker representation on boards as a cautionary tale.

Again the phrase "building a gigafactory not far from VW's headquarters" becomes a restrictive clause rather than an aside.

> Option 3: The American firm that builds a gigafactory not far from VW’s headquarters presumably views Germany’s system of powerful worker representation on boards as a cautionary tale.

Now it seems you want to talk about the general class of firms that build gigafactories not far from VW's headquarters, rather than a specific company. Since there is not likely to be many such companies, and probably only one, it seems silly to talk about them as if they are a group of companies rather than a single, specific company.

Comment: Just to clarify if the following two have the same meaning:   "The American firm which is building a gigafactory not far from VW’s headquarters presumably views Germany’s system of powerful worker representation on boards as a cautionary tale."  and "The American firm building a gigafactory not far from VW’s headquarters presumably views Germany’s system of powerful worker representation on boards as a cautionary tale." Basically, what I smell is that you can get rid of the "which is" part to share extra information about the previous sentence. Am I right in saying this?

Comment: Google the term "restrictive clause". With commas, it's a non-restrictive clause or aside that adds additional information. Without the commas it's a restrictive clause that identifies or specifies which company is being discussed. The "which is" just happens to be unnecessary for this particular wording.

Comment: "Restrictive **relative** clause". There are many kinds of clauses, identified by their syntactic properties. There are two kinds of relative clauses, restrictive (aka "integrated"), which are by far the more common, and nonrestrictive (I forget what CGEL calls them), like the previous clause beginning with _which_ and ending with _common_. Non-restrictive relative clauses are bounded intonationally by pitch dips, represented in writing by commas.

Comment: It's just worth pointing out that commas can indicate where a pause would go when reading the text aloud, and that those pauses also serve to tell the reader that a subclause is happening.  Also, the commas could be replaced by braces, eg "*The American firm (which is building a gigafactory not far from VW’s headquarters) presumably views Germany’s system of powerful worker representation on boards as a cautionary tale.*"